# Why are these Multiline equations not rendered?

Tags: equations

Here:

```
$$\begin{alignat}{2}
x(t) & = X+v\cos \theta t \\
y(t)& =Y+c\sin \theta t-\dfrac{1}{2}gt^2 \\
\end{alignat}$$
```

MathJax doesn't renderes it and so ShareLatex.com. Is there any particular reason?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc. You need to remove those `$$`

Comment: The evironment `alignat` doesn't needs to use double dollar signs, in the other hand, why you tagged this question as `multicolumn` if you don't use that package?

Comment: I believe that MathJax doesn't recognize `alignat`. Use `align` instead.

Comment: @Sigur MathJax is supposed to know `alignat`, see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands

Comment: @Udi: MathJax renders those equations fine, just try on http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic.html (without dollar signs) Edit: In a normal LaTeX document (as on ShareLaTeX) you need `\usepackage{amsmath}` of course.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T: Thanks a lot for the link. After adding the amsmath package in ShareLatex I get this error: Erroneous nesting of eqution structures; Why is it?

Comment: @UdiBehar as noted above you need to _remove_ the `$$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a particular reason: you must remove `$$` around the `alignat`.

While that construction works with MathJax, it's not a reason why it should work with LaTeX, where `$$` should instead *never* be used.

For a single numbered equation use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`; for your aligned equations there is `align`, which is better than `alignat` in this case. Each environment has the version with `*` at the end of the name for getting no number.

Note also that the last line *mustn't* be terminated by `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
x(t) & = X+v\cos \theta t \\
y(t)& =Y+c\sin \theta t-\dfrac{1}{2}gt^2
\end{alignat}

\begin{align}
x(t) & = X+v\cos \theta t \\
y(t)& =Y+c\sin \theta t-\dfrac{1}{2}gt^2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]